# How to declare an array of bools in C++?

Tags: c++, boolean

```
bool people[30][6];
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        people[i][j] = true;
```

what are  the values of `people[29][0]`, `people[29][1]`? Is it `true`, `false` or `NULL`?

Comment: Those values are beyond the range of the array.

Comment: Array of size `n` is indexed from `0` to `n-1`. Thus for `n=30` valid indexes are `0`-`29`.

Comment: Your question title does not reflect what you're asking in the body.

Comment: It's good that in the `for` loops you've used the ranges correctly (0 to less than 30 and 0 to less than 6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`people[30][1],people[30][2]` are undefined values - 30 is beyond the declared range of your array (29 is max).